# RoR: onchange in js doesn't work

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a list with actions and on that list I have used `.sortable` in js - it worked correctly.

actions.js:

```
$(function () {
  $("#actions").sortable({
    axis: 'y',
    handle: '.handle',
    update: function () {
      $.post($(this).data('update-url'), $(this).sortable('serialize'));
    }
  });
}
```

I need to add check to this list if given element has correct flag (true/false).

When i added `.onchange` i get :

```
Completed 500  in 58ms (ActiveRecord: 11.0ms)
ActionView::MissingTemplate - Missing template update_actions/sort, cms/sort, application/sort with {:formats=>[:html, :text, :js, :css, :ics, :csv, :vcf, :png, :jpeg, :gif, :bmp, :tiff, :mpeg, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json, :pdf, :zip], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}.
```

I don't know how to repair it.

Thank you.

Comment: Rails is complaining that it dint find a template to render for the action that was called. The action should render a template like a (JSON or .js.erb or sth) or render nothing (with `render :nothing => true`)

Comment: ^^ What he said. The bug is in your controller action for `sort`; this javascript is irrelevant.

Comment: Ok, i add it but it still doesn't work. I don't get 500 only. My js - onchnage - doesn't work.